# jQuery - insertAfter not functioning

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to move the `#whatsOnLink` to below the *"Get a Quote"* button across the site using jQuery and I'm having trouble on the jQuery side of things. If I remove the additional part of `.button` from the target then it will move fine but I need it to go inside the holding div.

```js
$('div[class^="grid"] a#whatsOnLink').each(
  function() {
    $(this).insertAfter($(this).closest('div[class^="grid_3"] div .button'));
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="grid_3 alpha omega selected cheapest">
  <div class="cheapest-body">

    <div class="cheapest-heading">
      <p>BEST VALUE</p>
    </div>

    <a id="whatsOnLink" href="">Test</a>

    <p class="latest-type">Silver apartment
      <br>from <span class="latest-offer-price">£75</span>  <span>pp</span>  <a class="lightbox lightbox-accomodation-more-info lightbox-added" href="/accommodation-overlays/bognor-regis-silver-apartment.aspx"><span>More Information</span></a>
    </p>

    <a class="button bookingEngine button-red" href="">
      <span>Get A Quote</span>
    </a>

    <img src="" class="grey-out-overlay">

  </div>
</div>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Regards,
Kieran

Comment: I hope you have only one item with id "whatsOnLink".

Comment: Do your selectors **have to** be constructed like that? `#whatsOnLink` should only exist once but I'm guessing you cannot modify the markup and hence the use of jQuery to move elements around, is this correct? Does `#whatsOnLink` appear outside of `.grid_3` or any `.grid_` element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this

```
$(this).closest('div[class^="grid_3"]').find('div .button')
```

Instead of

```
$(this).closest('div[class^="grid_3"] div .button')
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('div[class^="grid"] a#whatsOnLink').each(
    function() {
      $(this).insertAfter($(this).closest('div[class^="grid_3"]').find('div .button'));
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="grid_3 alpha omega selected cheapest">
  <div class="cheapest-body">

    <div class="cheapest-heading">
      <p>BEST VALUE</p>
    </div>

    <a id="whatsOnLink" href="">Test</a>

    <p class="latest-type">Silver apartment
      <br>from <span class="latest-offer-price">£75</span>  <span>pp</span>  <a class="lightbox lightbox-accomodation-more-info lightbox-added" href="/accommodation-overlays/bognor-regis-silver-apartment.aspx"><span>More Information</span></a>
    </p>

    <a class="button bookingEngine button-red" href="">
      <span>Get A Quote</span>
    </a>

    <img src="" class="grey-out-overlay">

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Excellent - finding this one working the best of the 2 fixes :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use `.next()`

```
$('div[class^="grid"] a#whatsOnLink').each(function() {
  $(this).insertAfter($(this).next().next());

  // OR

  // $(this).appendTo($(this).parent());
});
```

```js
$('div[class^="grid"] a#whatsOnLink').each(function() {
  $(this).insertAfter($(this).next().next());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="grid_3 alpha omega selected cheapest">
  <div class="cheapest-body">

    <div class="cheapest-heading">
      <p>BEST VALUE</p>
    </div>
    <a id="whatsOnLink" href="">Test</a>
    <p class="latest-type">Silver apartment
      <br>from <span class="latest-offer-price">£75</span>  <span>pp</span>  <a class="lightbox lightbox-accomodation-more-info lightbox-added" href="/accommodation-overlays/bognor-regis-silver-apartment.aspx"><span>More Information</span></a>
    </p>
    <a class="button bookingEngine button-red" href="">
      <span>Get A Quote</span>
    </a>
    <img src="" class="grey-out-overlay">
  </div>
</div>
```